# What statistical analysis should I use for comparing multiple variables at different time frames? (psychology experiment)

Tags: experiment-design, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, psychology

I'm planning a longitudinal psychology experiment where I want to compare levels of different variables over the course of an 8-week treatment.  i.e. I want to see any increase/decrease in variable A, B, and C at time frames of pre-treatment, 3 weeks, 6 weeks, and post-treatment, and see whether their changes are significant over the course of the treatment.

I also want to see if I can find out how the variables are related, because I suspect one of the variables mediates the other two.  I've read about mediation analysis and structural equation modelling to achieve this; am I correct in thinking these analysis methods are appropriate?

I'm very new to statistical analysis so I'm not sure if conducting this type of analysis is at all possible.  Any help would be really appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting yourself up to make life very difficult.

If you are asking whether variables increase or decrease over time, you should do a latent growth model, which can be done within a sem or mixed model framework. If you want to model three variables, you need to use sem.

Then you ask about mediation - now you want to do a cross lagged regression analysis, but you have treatment in there which makes things more complex.

Both of these have been combined into what's called the auto-regressive latent trait model - here's a paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1006.3804&rep=rep1&type=pdf , but these models are very difficult to identify (I have tried a few times, and I've never had one fit).

You are setting yourself a very difficult task. You say "I'm very new to statistical analysis" - these are hard models separately, combined they are very hard. I suggest you try to simplify your approach.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate this reply.  So realistically, I should just stick to the first part of the question and not be so greedy!

Comment: I was about to ask another question on your comment below, but it seems that the post has gotten deleted.  By repeated measures anova only 'views time as categorical and ignores the ordering', do you mean that it is not suitable for experiments measuring variables at ordered time frames, i.e. when orders have meaning?

Comment: Yes. You want to know not just if things are different, but if things are changing in a consistent direction. Say you have 3 week, 6 week and post treatment mean, and your mean differences are 10, 5, 0. Clearly something has happened - the effect of treatment as disappeared by the final measure, and it was dropping before. Repeated measures will say "On average, the difference is positive, and it's not the same at each time."